# Parse numbers from single digit html elements

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

I would like to find numbers on websites which have a specific digit length.

Finding normal numbers is easy, but I would also like to find numbers where the digits are separated into multiple HTML elements and also on different nesting levels.

I think one way would be to go down the tree to the last elements, check if it's a number and go up for x levels and check if the pattern repeats, extract the numbers. But I'm not sure how to find out if an element is on it's last branch.

I guess there is also leaner solution. Maybe someone has a better idea?

```
const body = `
<body>
  <div id="not-enogh-digits>
    213
  </div>
  <div id="normal-number>
    1235345
  </div>
  <div id="one-level-child-elements">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>3</span>
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>7</span>
  </div>
  <div id="multi-digit-elements">
    <span>12</span>
    <span>42</span>
    <span>62</span>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div id="multi-level-child-elements">
    <span>
      <b>
        1
      </b>
    </span>
    <span>
      <b>
        3
      </b>
    </span>
    <span>
      <b>
        4
      </b>
    </span>
    <span>
      <b>
        5
      </b>
    </span>
    <span>
      <b>
        7
      </b>
    </span>
    <span>
      <b>
        8
      </b>
    </span>
  </div>
  </section>
</body>
`;

const getNumbers = (minimumDigits, maxLevelsUp) => {
  const matches = [];

  // get easy numbers
  const easyNumbersRegex = />.*[\t\n\r\s]*(\d+)[\t\n\r\s]*.*<\//g;
  const regexResult = body.matchAll(easyNumbersRegex);
  const easyNumbers = Array.from(regexResult);
  easyNumbers.map((number) =>
    number.length >= minimumDigits ? matches.push(number[1]) : null
  );

  // get multi level numbers
  

  return matches;
};

console.log(getNumbers(2, 2));
```

Output:

```
[213, 1235345, 124262, 134578]
```

Comment: Good point, thanks. Updated.

Comment: You can use `element.innerText` to get the entire text of the element and its children. You could even do `document.body.innerText` if you want! Then parse that out.